# understanding google-maps-react library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, npm-scripts

I came across this [post](https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-apps-with-the-google-maps-api-and-google-maps-react) to integrate google-map with react
It uses [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react)
 As we can see on the library page,  it explains we can use
`import { GoogleApiWrapper } from google-maps-react`

Now in order to be a better js developer, I wish to understand how to understand this api directly from library
So I want to understand how to corroborate as well as not only this library, how do we move ahead with understanding the any library we want to use in our react-project primarily.
All help is very much appreciated, it will help all fellow developer take a leap in their skill!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to find out what is going on in a js library, always check the `index.js` file.

For example, in google-maps-react you'll find in root/index.js, this line

`export {wrapper as GoogleApiWrapper} from './GoogleApiComponent';`

Inside the GoogleApiComponent.js file you'll find that it has `wrapper` as a named export as well as the default export of the file.

**EDIT:**

In most libraries (as well as projects) you will find this standard where people define many modules in a folder and then export them from a single index.js file.

This is because with the import-export syntax of JS if you have a folder structure of

```
root
|-> a.js
|-> b
    |-> c.js
    |-> d.js
    |-> index.js
```

then you can import straight from the folder 'b', by using the index.js in the folder to define what exports are to come from b.

A sample index.js will look something like this

```
export * from './foo';
export {default as bar} from 'bar';
export {baz} from 'baz';
```

Comment: Thank you ManavM, as I refered to the google-maps-library it has something like `Object.defineProperty(exports, 'GoogleApiWrapper', {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
      return _GoogleApiComponent.wrapper;
    }
  });`

Comment: I will put some effort understanding this syntax, will get back as early as I can elaborate

Comment: Ahh now I see why you are confused. You see you are looking at the [build files](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/tree/master/dist) that are published by the library. If you want to learn about the library I suggest looking at the [source code](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/tree/master/src).

Comment: ok, Thank you ManavM, so basically the node modules do not have source code files is it always so?

Comment: Mostly...I have seen some libraries that put the source code in the node_modules but it is very rare. Usually you publish the built files. Especially since most of your library code needs to be transpiled before it can be published...otherwise you force the person using the library to transpile your library for you before it can be used.

Comment: happy to help :)